# Image style copy or clone

Tags: 7, media

Is there a UI way to clone/copy image style?

/admin/config/media/image-styles

lists all styles. I wish to modify one of them but I don't want to override it and I don't want to start from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

[imagecache_actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) module implements this for D7 (brand new, in 7.x-1.x-dev only yet). It is based on a feature request for D8: [#1403962](http://drupal.org/node/1403962). The dev version also implements a rudimentary export/import to copy between different systems (or the issue queue) without a need for features.

Comment: *NOTE*: This functionality is in the "Image Styles Admin" submodule of Imagecache Actions.